# Secure Hidden form Data $_POST

Tags: php, html, forms

I was just fiddling around in Chrome and realized that a hidden form element can be changed by a user in the Chrome inspector.

[image]

As you can see in the picture above any user can go in and edit the form in Chrome and then submit the form.

I'm curious if there is a way around this such as a more secure way of sending data to my files that I do not want to be changed by the user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Easy, don't put it in your form. So where can you put it? Store it in a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Comment: Simple, yet effective.